# Repeating code between two commands on a new page

Tags: loops

I have a quite complex code where I need to repeat a few lines (consisting of commands, for simplification here in MWE only a few words). In the MWE for printing the same as above in italic. The number of lines to be repeated changes from case to case, so the command should use two other commands (here `\begin{document}` and `\newpage`) as parameters for guidance. Can someone help me with this? Thanks a lot already!

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\LaTeX

Hi

Ciao

Bonjour

Hallo

Servus

\LaTeX

\newpage

\textit{
%Here should be a command to reapeat everything between \begin{document} and \newpage to be printed in italic
}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `NewEnviron` to capture the content with the `\BODY` macro and reuse it. The two pages appear as:

[image]

There is also `\NewDocumentEnvironment` from `xparse`, but that is currently marked as experimental:

```
\NewDocumentEnvironment{MyRepeatingEnvironment}{+b}{%
    #1
    \newpage
    \textit{#1}%
}{}%
```

This is yielding "Argument of \environment MyRepeatingEnvironment  has an extra }", but don't exactly  know why.

#### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{environ}

\NewEnviron{MyRepeatingEnvironment}{%
    \BODY
    \newpage
    \textit{\BODY}%
}%

\begin{document}
\begin{MyRepeatingEnvironment}
\LaTeX

Hi

Ciao

Bonjour

Hallo

Servus

\LaTeX
\end{MyRepeatingEnvironment}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, it does exactly what I was looking for :)